# Linear Regression (Gradient descent update) - training set err is more than testing

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

My algorithm is like:

data is stored as:

```
data = [record1, record2, ... ]
    where record1 is [1, x1, x2 ..., x_m] m feature values for that record
theta is parameter of linear regression function, theta is vector of size m+1
y is true label, again array of length, len(data). (y[0] is true value for record 0)
```

Linear regression Stochastic update:

```
while True:
    for i in range(len(data)):
        x = data[i]
        for t in range(0, m):
            theta[t] = theta[t] - my_lambda * (np.dot(theta, x) - y[i]) * x[t]
        j_theta = compute_J_of_theta(data, y, theta)
    print "Iteration #: ", iterations, " j_theta ", j_theta
    if j_theta < 5000:
        #print "******************** FINALLY CONVERGED!!!! ********************" 
        break

compute_j_of_theta(data, y, theta):
"""
Convergence criteria,
compute J(theta) = 1/2M sum (h_theta(x_t) - y_t)**2
"""
temp = 0
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    x = data[i]
    temp += (np.dot(theta, x) - y[i])**2
return temp/2*M
```

my_lambda is very small 
Initially theta is 0 vector of size m+1

Que: Training set err is more than testing ... WHY? what's wrong with this ?
EDIT 1:
It was my stupid mistake in calculating err

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: You don't do parallel theta updates, you dot the current theta while updating it.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut didn't get it  ... I thought this is how Stochastic update looks like ... could you please make it clear? Thanks!

Comment: @codemuncher stochastic means that you are updating the weights after a single training item. Parallel means that you update the completed new theta vector after you looped over all M features so you do not manipulate the parameters while calculating with them. So either put the `np.dot(theta, x)` out of the loop or rewrite the loop so it doesn't use the updating theta anymore.